# Preserving white spaces before while transfering text from textarea to table cell

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need your help,

How can the regex/replace coding be amended such that I would not only be able to also preserve the line breaks after the text but to also preserve the extra white spaces in front of the text, in between text and after the text.

I've attached a pic of what the result is currently. The expected end result should mirror that of the first text area

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function test() {

//textarea to table cell
var x = document.getElementById('txt1').value.replace(/\r?\n/g,'<br>')

//table cell to textarea

document.getElementById("table1").children[0].children[0].innerHTML = x

var y = document.getElementById("table1").children[0].children[0].innerHTML

//some processing first to replace the <br>'s before the final output

y = y.replace(/\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*/g, '\n')

document.getElementById("txt2").value = y

}


</script>

</head>

<body>
<textarea style="height: 200px;" id="txt1"></textarea>
<br>
<table id="table1"><tr><td>cell data1</td></tr></table>
<br>
<input type="button" value="test it" onclick="test()">
<br>
<textarea style="height: 200px;" id="txt2"></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you want to _preserve_ everything, what is getting replaced ?

Comment: It's not clear what the question here is but to preserve whitespace in your HTML output, you can use the `<pre>` tags around the raw text.

Comment: well if you have text from a textarea and it is being written to a cell as data, it does not keep the line breaks. So the replace function finds the line breaks, and re-strings it using <br>'s. Then at the end the string is restrung so that the <br>s from the table are converted to proper line breaks in a textarea.

Comment: It seems that, at the end if I have any spaces in front of my text, they are disregarded as such.

Comment: Then, `\r?\n => <br>` and `<br> => \n` should be inverse operations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to encode leading and multiple whitespace like so:

```
//textarea to table cell
var x = document.getElementById('txt1').value.replace(/\r?\n/g,'<br>')
        .replace(/^\s|\s(?=\s)/g, '&nbsp;');
```

some lines  later do the reverse:

```
y = y.replace(/\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*/g, '\n').replace('&nbsp;', ' ')
```

Comment: Martin, this works great, the table cell resembles that of the first text entered in the first text area but now the end result has alful &nbsp;'s in front of my text appearing in the second textarea. Anyway to also convert them into proper text spacing?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
document.getElementById("table1").children[0].children[0].innerHTML = x;
```

to

```
document.getElementById("table1").children[0].children[0].innerHTML = "<pre>" + x + "</pre>";
```